# how to pick up rgb color value of a pixel from a mouse click

Tags: c, opengl, mouse, mouseevent, glut

It might be a very naive question but i am a bit stuck.
I am writing my first opengl programme and I want to pick up the R value of a pixel, of a point that i got from mouse click.
I am clueless about how to use glReadPixels function.

```
void myMouseFunc( int button, int state, int x, int y ) {
    if ( button==GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state==GLUT_DOWN ) {

        glReadPixels(x,y,0.1,0.1,GL_RED,GL_INT, pixel);

        glutPostRedisplay();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is pretty clear:

http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml

```
GLubyte pixel;
glReadPixels(x, windowHeight - y - 1, 1, 1, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &pixel);
```

Comment: I am using GL_INT and i am getting same R value for pixels that i have given different colors using glColor3f().

Comment: Did you make the changes Andreas suggest? Note specifically that width and height should be specified in pixels (not 0.1 like in your question) and that the y-coordinate is inverted (from the bottom).

Comment: @Nitin Keep in mind that if using `GL_INT`, the [0,1] range of the color value is converted to the 32bit integer range (in contrast to the [0,255] you might expect)